# Many instance variables or hash with many keys?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

In Sinatra application I have a code

```
gef '/123' do
  @var1 = # some calculations
  @var2 = # some calculations
  #..... many of them

  haml(:"view123")
end
```

and all of the instance variables are used in `view123`. I wonder, will there be any benefit of using the hash instead of many variables like this:

```
gef '/123' do
  hash_var = {}
  hash_var[:var1] = # some calculations
  hash_var[:var2] = # some calculations
  #..... many of them

  haml(:"view123")
end
```

Comment: The memory you'll save will be negligible if you save any at all. Concentrate on making your code readable and maintainable and you'll save far more money in the long run.

Comment: Downvoted for asking the question in a misleading way. If your question was about memory it should mention memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are on the right track, and it's hard to advise in this very abstract sense, but in general that `# some calculations` looks like business logic. And business logic belongs in models.

How about a model instead?  Make a new class that performs these calculations, then instantiate it and pass the instance to your view.  Your controller/route handler remains lean and clean, and many many lines of calculations are all tucked into a file dedicated to just that thing. Neat and tidy.

```
get '/123' do
  @calc = CrazyCalculator.new
  haml(:view123)
end
```

view123.erb:

```
<ul>
  <li>Calc1: <%= @calc.calc1 %></li>
  <li>Calc2: <%= @calc.calc2 %></li>
  <li>Calc3: <%= @calc.calc3 %></li>
  <li><!-- many other calculation methods --></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I mean, will I save the memory if use hash instead of a lot of instance variables?

Comment: @AlanDert You only said "will there be any benefit?" in your question, and there is benefit to using a model, it's good maintainable code to use model classes properly.  But save memory? Nope. Not even a little.